# DelegatingHandler hangs when returning Task<HttpResponseMessage>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, task-parallel-library

This is my very simple class that demonstrates the problem:

```
public class SimpleHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return new Task<HttpResponseMessage>(
                        () => new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));

            //return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

The expected behaviour is a 401 response. If I debug it, execution arrives at the return statement and continues when I hit F5 but the http request never returns and http client ends up waiting until timeout.

I'm really confused because I'm doing what the compiler is telling me: return a `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`. The call to base.SendAsync works just fine. What am I missing here?

**Edit:**

Ok, so I found out that

```
return Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
```

works as expected. However, I'd like to understand why the approach above is failing? In both cases, I'm creating a `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` Why do I get the expected behaviour only in the second case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a big difference. The Task created with the constructor represents a Task that has not run yet and as such, does not have a result set yet. In your case no work has to be done so there is no need to create and run a Task. Otherwise [You should use Task.Run instead of a constructor](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html).

And since you only created the Task in your example, and did not call `Start()` it will have the status `Created` and will never complete on its own since it won't be started. Hence your process hangs because further down the pipeline the system will wait for the task to complete.

The second Task, created using `FromResult`, represents a Task that has been completed and has the set value as the result.

Check de `Status` property of both Task and note the differences. (Created versus RanToCompletion)

Since you do not have actual work to do you should stick to using `FromResult`.

Comment: `Task.Run` doesn't seem appropriate here. Why would you delegate to the thread pool for this? `Task.FromResult` seems more correct.

Comment: @PeterBons my confusion stems from relying on the return type alone. How am I supposed to know that I'm expected to return a Task that has been started? What if the calling code/framework is going to start the task itself? Your answer makes sense but only if one makes the assumption that the task should be started. I just saw no indication of this assumption anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the static Task.FromResult method which is used to create a Task that is a wrapper around a specific value:

```
Task.FromResult<HttpResponseMessage>(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
```